# Undirected Graph - > Depth-First Search C programming - counts number of connected components

Tags: c, depth-first-search

This is now fixed. It successfully creates an UNDIRECTED graph's Adjacency list. Also, it performs a Depth-first Search and counts the total number of connected components in the graph, while also keeping count of the number of vertices in the smallest component. 
Thank you @n.m

P.S. - few of the array's are not needed for this problem but I put them nevertheless.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 1000
int time=0;
int smallest_component = 100000;
int count=0;

//these are the value that will be used to mark vertices
enum 
{
    white, gray, black
}color;

// A structure to represent an adjacency list node
typedef struct _Node
{
    int dest;
    int color;
    struct _Node* next;
}Node;

/* This is the structure of the adjacency list
* It simply has an array of Nodes
*/
typedef struct _Adj
{
    Node *list;  // pointer to head node of list
}Adj;

int D[MAX];
int F[MAX];
int Color[MAX];

// Prototypes
void printGraph(Adj *list, int vertices);
void addEdge(Adj *list, int start, int end);
void DFS(Adj* list, int vertex);


int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
 FILE *in = NULL;
int vertex1=0, vertex2=0;
int vertex_count=0;
Node *head = NULL;

int v=1;
int u=1;
int connected_components = 0;

//make sure enough arguments are supplied
if(argc!=2)
{
    printf("hw1 <vertices-file>\n");
    return 1;
}

//open the file
in = fopen(argv[1], "r");

//check to see if the file was opened
if(in == NULL)
{
    printf("The file could not be opened");
    return 2;
}

//START THE INSERTION OF THE VERTICES

//grab the first number. It is the number of vertices
fscanf(in, "%d", &vertex_count);
int vertices = vertex_count + 1;

//Create the struct pointer and call the function to create the Graph
Adj* list = (Adj*)malloc(sizeof(Adj)*vertices);

for(v=1; v<vertices; v++){
    Color[v] = white;
}


//run through each pair of numbers 
while(fscanf(in, "%d %d", &vertex1, &vertex2)!=EOF)
{   
    // create the first list    
    addEdge(list, vertex1, vertex2);
}

printf("\n\n");

Node *temp;

//run through the graph's nodes
for (v = 1; v < vertices; v++)
 {
    count = 0;
    if(Color[v] == white){
        DFS(list, v);
        connected_components++;

        if(smallest_component>count)
            smallest_component=count;
    }
 }

printf("The number of connected components is %d\n", connected_components);

printf("The smallest component has %d vertices\n", smallest_component);

free(list);

//printGraph(myGraph);
return 0;
}

//Run a DFS given the Adjacency list and vertex in the list
 void DFS(Adj* list, int vertex)
{
count++;
//printf("\nI am in DFS with node %d \n", vertex);

Color[vertex] = gray;

time = time + 1;
D[vertex] = time;
Node *temp;

for(temp = list[vertex].list; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
{   
        if(Color[temp->dest] == white)
            DFS(list, temp->dest);
}

//get the new time, color, and end time
time = time+1;
F[vertex] = time;

//this means that we backtracked and now the node is black
Color[vertex] = black;
 }

/*
* This function creates the edge between the two vertices.
 * Since we have an UNDIRECTED graph, when I create the edges, I create them for both       vertex and destination
  */
void addEdge(Adj* list, int v, int dest)
{
//create the edge between vertex and destination
Node* temp = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
temp->next = list[v].list;
temp->dest = dest;
list[v].list = temp;

//create the edge between dest and vertex
Node* temp2 = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
temp2->next = list[dest].list;
temp2->dest = v;
list[dest].list = temp2;
}
```

Comment: How do you define connected components in a directed graph?

Comment: 3-6-4, is considered a connected component, 5-9-10 is another one. Is this what you were asking?

Comment: No. I have asked for a definition, not for examples.

Comment: "In graph theory, a connected component of an undirected graph is a subgraph in which any two vertices are connected to each other by paths, and which is connected to no additional vertices in the supergraph" - Wikipedia

Comment: n.m , I was not clear enough in my description and I did not read you question very thoroughly: my grap is Undirected graph so I don't need ot pay attention to the order. My problem is not with that.

Comment: Step through your code line-by-line with a debugger, and compare its behaviour to what you expect to happen. At some point, it will diverge, and then you will have found your bug.

Comment: The problem is that you are not building an undirected graph. You are building a directed graph. Your edges have a start and an end, and you can only travel from the start to the end and not back.

Comment: @n.m THANK you so much!!! I was wondering if I am doing something wrong with the building of the list itself because when I print my Adjacency list it only shows one way connection but I wasn't sure if that is my problem. Thank you so much once again. Please mark it as answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure represents an *directed* graph, and the DFS connected components count algorithm only works for *undirected* graphs. The results will not be correct.

You need to adapt your data structure to represent an undirected graph. The easiest way to do that is to add, for each original edge `(a, b)`, an opposite edge `(b, a)`. Just add another call to `addEdge`.

Comment: Thank you @n.m . I have since edited the code so now it functions the way it is supposed to. This way people can still use the code. Thanks again.